# Error connecting to Hive on Server from my local Denodo

Tags: hive, denodo

I am trying to connect to hive 1.2 which sits on a remote server. I am trying to connect from my local laptop. I am getting an error as : **Unable to establish connection: Could not establish connection to <> : java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused: connect**

[image: Screen-shot of the Denodo Setup]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Ouch... that HiveServer1 protocol is not supported any more, and Hive V0.10 is not "current" since end of 2013 -- the typical Hadoop cluster likely uses V1.2 or even V2.0 >> Try the HS2 protocol i.e. `jdbc:hive2:` as explained here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients  and a JDBC driver for Hive V1.x

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Hive server is not accepting connections on that port. Make sure that the IP Address and port are correct. (10000 seems strange to me.)

It could also be a security issue with a firewall blocking all outside connections, this is a very common scenario in business environments. Check with the people running the server that you can connect from whatever network you are attempting to connect from.

Comment: _"port 10000 seems strange to me"_ -- welcome to the Hadoop world!